# How can I store more than one word inside a txt file into a String in one sitting?

Tags: java, arrays, file

So I have a really long list of words inside a txt called `dictionary.txt`. It has one word, then it skips to a new line and has the next one as follows:

```
priceably
southwesterly
semipapal
genuine
cardiotoxicities
shoeman
Utahan
ungeodetically
Schurman
...
```

I am still struggling to find a way to store them all in an array of Strings without having to do it one by one.

This is what I got so far:

```java
        String[] words = new String[0];
        int i = 0;
  
        try
        {
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(new File("dictionary.txt"));
            String line;
            while (scnr.hasNext())
            {
              line = scnr.nextLine();
              String[] lineWords = line.split("\r?\n|\r"); 
              words = concatenate(words, lineWords);
            }
            scnr.close();
        }
```

How can I optimize this better so that the program finishes this process faster?

Comment: `line = scnr.nextLine();` that reads one line. You don't need `lineWords` after that. You only read one line. Also, `List<String> words = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("dictionary.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: :  `String[] words = new String[0];` Why do you want an array of no elements?  What is the code for your `concatenate` method? Does it create a new array each time? If so, that doesn't seem efficient. Better to start with an oversized array, keep track of the number of elements actually in use, and expand the array when it is discovered to be too small. Consider using an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of an array, because `ArrayList` does that.

Comment: Thank you you two! The line List<String> words = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("dictionary.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8); was really useful!

I didn't know about these methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this is useful for anyone in the future. This is how I implemented the solution in the comments (I didn't keep using array lists because I barely know how to use them and the deadline was encroaching forward to even start learning that now):

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US); // formats the amount of nanoseconds displayed

        List<String> words = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("dictionary.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // reads txt file and stores it in an array list
  
        String[] transformed = words.toArray(new String[words.size()]); // transforms array list into a String array...
        String[] wordsToSort = transformed.clone(); // makes a copy to safely change it in the future...
  
        // Testing Sorting algorithms......
```

This line `List<String> words = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("dictionary.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);` stores more than 600000 elements into an array list in one sitting. In this way, you do not need a loop to store them all one-by-one.